# Cannot connect to Google Account on Internet Account - OSX 10.12.3

Tags: mail.app, gmail, keychain

From this morning I cannot use anymore any account based on Gmail (neither work account). It asked me for password and every time I insert the correct one, it gives me a "grey" screen (check the screenshot below). I tried already to delete all the google/gmail entries on login/all from Keychain Access, to reboot my Macbook but the problem doesn't get solved. Anyone knows how to solve this? Thank you!

I created another thread because I cannot comment there (50 points needed and because the solution applied there is not working). As I said in the comment probably it was working only for an older version of OSX.

[image]

Comment: I cannot comment there because I don't have enough points. Anyway that solution doesn't work for me (and probably was thought for an older version of OSX).